# Bootcamp Removal: Boots back into windows

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I had installed a bootcamp partition to try out windows 10 on my 15" 2017 MBP, and removed it. After removing it, the system boots onto the windows partition, revealing the "Windows is Broken press F1, F8, or F11 for boot options.

When this happens, if I hold down the TouchID sensor, there is a temporary workaround where I can hold the option key on boot to change it back to macOS.

How do I stop this tedious behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the tedious behaviour, you must open System Preferences in the macOS partition, then go to Startup Disk, then unlock the panel and select "Macintosh HD" instead of the non-existent partition that it has been booting to. Now lock the preference pane, and it will load back into macOS without fail.